# How to remove all the <tr> from a table except the first one using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am having a table and I want to remove all `<tr>` of the table except the first one. How can I do this.?

Comment: Is the first row semantically a header? If so it may be better to change your markup a bit, and it would result in even simpler script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several methods here, the most terse is to use the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$('#tableID tr:gt(0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 6):

Is there a special meaning to the first row? I am going to go out on a limb and say the first row is likely the row which contains the column headings.

If so, one easy option is to put the first row in a `<thead>` and all the body rows in a `<tbody>`.  Then you could simply do:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').remove();
```

This also gives your HTML more semantic meaning.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#theTable tr').slice(1).remove();
```

This uses a fully valid CSS selector to get all the table rows, then takes [a `.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) of the set starting with index `1` (the second row), and finally [calls `.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the rows.

The valid CSS selector is important because it will allow jQuery/Sizzle to successfully utilize the native `querySelectorAll` method, which will provide an extremely fast selection.

`querySelectorAll` is supported in many browsers, including `IE8`.

---

**EDIT:**

Though you asked for a jQuery solution, I thought I'd throw in a native DOM API solution since it will perform faster than anything else, and it's really pretty simple.

```
var rows = document.getElementById('theTable').rows;

while( rows[1] )
    rows[1].parentNode.removeChild( rows[1] );
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-sizzle-selectors i was testing your affirmation, you stand correct, but later browsers appear to enjoy the new css3 selectors =)

Comment: @Couto: Good point. The `'table :first-child ~ tr'` is going to be a valid selector in most (perhaps all) cases, though it could technically fail to meet the requirements if there are multiple `<tbody>` elements. It would be great if `:gt()` or `:not(:first)` were valid selectors.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'll jump on the bandwagon and provide some solutions:

If you're using `thead` for the first row, just drop the `tr`s in the `tbody`:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').remove();
```

If you're not using `thead` you can get the subsequent rows in numerous ways. I highly suggest looking through the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/)

Here are a few examples of how you can remove the rows:

1. `$('#myTable tr + tr').remove();`
2. `$('#myTable tr:gt(0)').remove();`
3. `$('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').remove();`
4. `$('#myTable').find('tr').not(':first-child').remove();`
5. `$('#myTable tr:first-child').siblings().remove();`

Really it comes down to how creative you want to be in your selectors, and what your intentions are. I didn't provide a filter example, but using `filter` will allow you to call `end` and continue chaining from a parent element.

You'll have to do some unit-tests to see which of these methods are the fastest, or don't if it's not as important.

Comment: Those are some good, creative solutions, though numbers 1, 3, 4 and 5 would fail to provide the desired result if there's more than one `<tbody>`. Although I'd grant that that's not likely the case.

Comment: @patrick dw I suppose that's true, but if they were using multiple `tbody`s they are likely using a `thead` in which case the first example would be the best choice. Good catch though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myTable').find('tr').not(":first").remove();
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TwqN3/

Comment: an alternative to this, from another SO post: `$('#someTableSelector tr:not(:first)').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [next siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/):

> $('table :first-child ~ tr').remove();

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/TwqN3/2/
(Thanks to Stefan Kendall! I didn't knew jsfiddle.)